# craft.feeds does not appear to be working

Tags: feed

I want do display a financial widget on a front-end of a site.

[image: Widget]

The financial data is actually a feed:

http://test.solutions.vwdservices.com/customers/vastned.com/page-modules/widgetrss

But it's not working on the frontend. No content.

```
{% set feedUrl = "http://test.solutions.vwdservices.com/customers/vastned.com/page-modules/widgetrss" %}
{% set limit = 1 %}
{% set items = craft.feeds.getFeedItems(feedUrl, limit) %}

{% for item in items %}
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
        <div class="number">{{ item.title }}</div>
        <small class="{{ item.authors[0].name }}">{{ item.summary }}<br />{{ item.date }}</small>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my feed data:

```
<Feed xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Title>Aandelen Vastned</Title>
<Id>0</Id>
<Updated>2014-08-22T17:29:40</Updated>
<Entry>
<Title>€ 36,81</Title>
<Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Id>
<Updated>2014-08-22T17:29:40</Updated>
<Summary>0,00%</Summary>
<Author>
<Name>Grijs</Name>
</Author>
</Entry>
</Feed>
```

Answer (score 1):

[FeedsService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/FeedsService) uses [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) for feed parsing, but it currently does expose any errors that SimplePie may be returning when connecting to a feed.

> A feed could not be found at http://test.solutions.vwdservices.com/customers/vastned.com/page-modules/widgetrss. This does not appear to be a valid RSS or Atom feed.

Here's the error it's returning when connecting to that feed.

We'll update FeedsService to return any errors that come back from SimplePie, too.